# How do I create this reference mapping in Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Using Fluent NHibernate I need a clue how to map my Invoice class.

```
public class Buyer
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string TaxRegNo { get; set; } 
    // .... more properties....
}

public class Invoice
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual int IdBuyer { get; set; }
    public virtual Buyer Buyer { get; set; } 
    // ....more properties
}
```

The problem is that I want to have in Invoice class:

- BuyerId - just an integer ID for reference and foregin key relationship
- a copy of almost all buyer properties (its accounting document and properties cannot be changed after confirmation) - as component

I tried to this using following mapping but it doesn't work

```
    public InvoiceMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);

        References(x => x.IdBuyer);
        Component(x => x.Buyer, BuyerMap.WithColumnPrefix("buyer_"));
    // ....more properties
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would normally not map both the foreign key and the child object. If you do map both, then do this in the mapping (or similar):

```
References(x => x.Buyer);
Map(x => x.IdBuyer).Column("BuyerId").Not.Insert().Not.Update();
```

Then you don't double up on the column name in SQL statements, which causes errors around mismatched numbers of parameters.